Discord selfbot discord slash using discum
import discum
import time

botID = 824119071556763668
guildID = 1186040951794307073
channelID = 1309665693997862912
token = "token"

bot = discum.Client(token=token, log=True)

def send_glist_command():
    try:
        data = {
            "name": "glist",
            "type": 1,
        }
        bot.triggerSlashCommand(botID, channelID, guildID=guildID, data=data)
        print("Sent '/glist' command.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending '/glist' command: {e}")

def start_bot(resp):
    if resp.event.ready:
        print("Bot is ready!")
        while True:
            send_glist_command()
            time.sleep(60)

bot.gateway.command(func=start_bot)
bot.gateway.run()


Slash commands won't work using discum also spams my console with a lot of green stuff, I don't really know discum so that's just like the first thing I made with it.
